# How to align Bootstrap cards horizontally in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am having a problem retrieving data from MySQL database. I am using Bootstrap for the front-end. I am fetching the cards using the following code:

```
<?php 
    require 'config.php';
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM contents";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        //Check if there is data
        $check_data = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;
        if($check_data) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
?>
    
    <div class="card-group">
    <div class="container py-5">
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <img src="images/<?php echo $row['images'] ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                                        <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['short_desc']; ?></h3>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <?php echo $row['long_desc']; ?>
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

           <?php
       }
        }
    ?>
```

but the cards are aligned vertically not horizontally which is not what I want as seen here:

[image: Vertical Alignment of cards php]

Comment: Well that's probably because you put each card into its own row element, which makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: ok let me try to fix it abit. Thanks @CBroe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
    
   <div class="row">
   
   
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="https://tipsmake.com/data1/thumbs/how-to-extract-img-files-in-windows-10-thumb-bzxI4IDgg.jpg" class="w-100">
        <h5>Sample Img</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="https://tipsmake.com/data1/thumbs/how-to-extract-img-files-in-windows-10-thumb-bzxI4IDgg.jpg" class="w-100">
        <h5>Sample Img</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="https://tipsmake.com/data1/thumbs/how-to-extract-img-files-in-windows-10-thumb-bzxI4IDgg.jpg" class="w-100">
        <h5>Sample Img</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="https://tipsmake.com/data1/thumbs/how-to-extract-img-files-in-windows-10-thumb-bzxI4IDgg.jpg" class="w-100">
        <h5>Sample Img</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is simple example your want too this
try this also above code

```
<div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <img src="https://tipsmake.com/data1/thumbs/how-to-extract-img-files-in-windows-10-thumb-bzxI4IDgg.jpg" class="w-100">
            <h5>Sample Img</h5>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

above code just put only your while loop

Comment: Thanks alot @yashpatel. I really appreciate your time Sir. But since youre more experienced could you help me and tell me whats the problem may be if you dont mind. Like according to my code what could have led to the cards being displayed vertically?

Comment: Welcome @han, why not, You can see what your output and you can do it that way, There are many other ways you can do this

Comment: Thanks alot any more way I can do this would like to have a multiple of them. Thanks alot for your time sir

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="card-group">
   <div class="container py-5">
      <div class="row mt-4">
         <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM contents";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
             //Check if there is data
              $check_data = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;
            
               if($check_data) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
            
               ?>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $row['images'] ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                  <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                  <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['short_desc']; ?></h3>
                  <p class="card-text">
                     <?php echo $row['long_desc']; ?>
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?php
            }
             }
            ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer @yashpatel but the problem still exists. could this be because of my css?

Comment: sorry my mistack now try this answer

Comment: i am some editing in my answer

Comment: ok sir.Thanks alot for helping...